# How to use Itext to add an image file into an existing PDF, and declare a unique name for it?

Tags: image, pdf, itext, unique

In order to find an added image file and replace it with another image file when I read a PDF next time, I want to use Itext to add an image file into an existing PDF, and declare a unique name for it. 
My code:

```
    final PdfName key = new PdfName("MY_SIGN_KEY");
    final PdfName val = new PdfName("MY_SIGN_VAL");

    Image signImage=Image.getInstance(signPngFile.getAbsolutePath());
    signImage.setAlignment(1);
    signImage.scaleAbsolute(newWidth, newHeight);
    signImage.setAbsolutePosition(200,200);

     PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
     PdfImage stream = new PdfImage(signImage, "", null);
     stream.put(key,val);// a unique name for it.(设置唯一标识符)

     //PdfIndirectObject ref=over.getPdfWriter().addToBody(stream);
     //signImage.setDirectReference(ref.getIndirectReference()); 
     over.addImage(signImage);
```

Comment: You are using code from my book that explains how to meet your requirement. What is your question? It seems that you already know the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't describe clearly, the above code can add image to PDF. But the name is not associated with the image.
If the code is not commented:

        
PdfIndirectObject ref = over. GetPdfWriter (.) addToBody (stream);
SignImage. SetDirectReference (ref. GetIndirectReference ());

        
Images can be added to the PDF. The name is correct association, but the whole picture is black.

Comment: So you are trying to create a PDF with an image like this: [SpecialId](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#622-specialid.java). You then want to find that image using the ID like this: [ResizeImage](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#621-resizeimage.java). The problem is that when you use `ref`, you get a black image. Maybe you should rephrase your question so that it focus on that problem.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply. Actually I writed those codes after watching the method you said. It could create new files. But for the existing files, I don't know how to deal with them.

Comment: any progress on adding png image issue? when I add png item and use `ref` I get black background on transparent part of the png image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and it works for me. See the [AddImageWithID](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/image-examples-itext5/adding-image-existing-file) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG);
    PdfImage stream = new PdfImage(image, "", null);
    stream.put(new PdfName("ITXT_SpecialId"), new PdfName("123456789"));
    PdfIndirectObject ref = stamper.getWriter().addToBody(stream);
    image.setDirectReference(ref.getIndirectReference());
    image.setAbsolutePosition(36, 400);
    PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    over.addImage(image);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

In this example, I take a file named [hello.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/hello.pdf) and I add an image named [bruno.jpg](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/images/bruno.jpg) with the file [hello_with_image_id.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/stamper/cmp_hello_with_image_id.pdf) as result.

The image doesn't look black:

[image]

The ID is added:

[image]

Can you try the code I shared and see if the problem persists.

I can think of one reason why you'd get a black image: in our code, we assume that a single image is added. In the case of JPEG, this is always the case. In the case of PNG or GIF though, adding one source image could result in two images being added. Strictly speaking, PDF doesn't support transparent images (depending on how you interpret the concept of transparent images). Whenever you add a single source image with transparent parts, two images will be added to the PDF: one opaque image and one image mask. The combination of the opaque image and the image mask results in something that is perceived as a transparent image. Maybe this is what happens in your case.

Comment: Is it an image problem or Itext does not support an image with transparent information (PNG)? I tried to make the background of the image non-transparent, and the above code would work. My need is to add an image with a transparent background. This will not overwrite the original contents of the PDF, and the next can change to the image to replace. 
PS: If you do not add the name of the image associated with the code, but can normally display PNG images.
I'm in the android environment development.

Comment: iText supports transparent PNG images; PDF doesn't. Your design of adding a unique ID to a transparent PNG is flawed as there is no such thing as one transparent PNG in a PDF; there is the opaque image and its image mask.